# CTE with Linked Server: Mulitpart Identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, linked-server, sap-erp

Interesting issue. I have the following CTE that JOINs some tables from a Linked Server which is our SAP data. This CTE is in a stored procedure and then executed via a SQL Server Agent Job on a timer (every 10 minutes). This ran fine for almost 20 hours and then dies with a multipart identifier could not be bound error (exact error below CTE).

Server running the job: SQL Server 2008 R2 (no SP)

Linked Server: SQL Server 2005 SP3 housing SAP

CTE:

```
WITH TaktValues ([Counter], NODE, PLNNR) AS 
(
    SELECT 
       MAX(plpo1.ZAEHL) AS [Counter], MAX(plpo1.PLNKN) AS NODE, plpo1.PLNNR 
    FROM 
       etl.PLPO plpo1
    GROUP BY plpo1.PLNNR
)
SELECT 
    s022.AUFNR AS WorkOrder,
    (CASE
        WHEN plpo.SPLIM = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE plpo.VGW01/plpo.SPLIM
        END) AS TaktTime
INTO 
    [plc].[TaktTime]
FROM 
    etl.S022 s022
INNER JOIN 
    etl.AFPO afpo on afpo.AUFNR = s022.AUFNR
INNER JOIN 
    etl.AFKO afko on afko.AUFNR = s022.AUFNR
INNER JOIN 
    etl.PLPO on plpo.PLNNR = afko.PLNNR
INNER JOIN 
    TaktValues ON plpo.PLNNR = TaktValues.PLNNR 
               AND plpo.ZAEHL = TaktValues.[Counter] 
               AND plpo.PLNKN = TaktValues.NODE
WHERE 
    s022.AUFNR IN (SELECT DISTINCT WorkOrder FROM plc.AlarmData)
ORDER BY 
    s022.AUFNR DESC
```

Error:

> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "Tbl1008.AUFNR" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "Tbl1008.AUFNR" could not be bound.

Comment: I don't see any 4 part names for linked server references in that SQL... ?

Comment: "Tbl1008.AUFNR" is a big red spot to me since it's not in your query. I expect it's a sub-component used in a view or other dependant sub-object; possibly that view is being recreated or changed by the system over time causing the error.

Comment: to the 4 part naming -> the call is being made through synonyms.

Comment: The tbl1008 I believe is being generated for the remote query to the other server (looking at the execution plan). it does seem strange though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the complete reference to the linked servers as stated in "The multi-part identifier "Tbl1008.AUFNR" could not be bound." You need to specify the complete name of the linked server's objects for the job to be able to bound the table object. Do it as follows:

[server_name].[database_name].[schema_name].[table_name]

Comment: I am running this through a synonym, do I need to do a 4 part name rather then the syn?

Comment: Just went through and used the 4 part name and had no change.